# onCreate method not getting called

Tags: android

I have following method inside a `ActionBar.TabListener` method and when I am calling the `setContentView` I am expecting it to call `onCreate` method for that view:
But that method is not called here.

so, how can I create an activity outside of the onCreate method?

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                switch (tabPosition) {
                case 0:
                    setContentView(R.layout.class_view);
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.class_view);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCreate` method is not part of the lifecycle of a `View`; it's for an `Activity` (or `Fragment`). `onView` is not called when you change the content view of an activity (or fragment). Calling `setContentView` does not create an activity; it is already created.

Comment: thn how can i initilize an activity from other class, lets say for navigation purposes?

Comment: @Maven - Create an `Intent` and call `startActivity`. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: @Maven - Also see the guide topic [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).